# Kustomize - Imported (resource) patch doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I am not managing to include a kustomization.yaml that only contains patches. As a minimal example of the problem I'm solving, I can illustrate with the folder structure below:

```
.
├── kustomization.yaml
├── nested
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── serviceaccount-patch.yaml
└── service-account.yaml
```

The files are:

```
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization 
metadata:
  name: top
resources:
  - service-account.yaml
  - nested

# service-account.yaml
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: base
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false

# nested/kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization 
metadata:
  name: nested
patches:
  - path: serviceaccount-patch.yaml
    target:
      kind: ServiceAccount
      name: base

# nested/serviceaccount-patch.yaml
- op: replace
  path: /metadata/name
  value: replaced
```

The patch is not applied. When putting the patch straight into `kustomization.yaml` it does work. I'd like to keep this structure, as my actual use case is to have the following:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── env
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   │   └── service-account.yaml
│   │   └── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── shared
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│       └── pod.yaml
├── overlay
│   └── dev
│       ├── env
│       │   ├── app
│       │   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│       │   │   └── serviceaccount-patch2.yaml
│       │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│       │   └── serviceaccount-patch.yaml
│       ├── kustomization.yaml
│       └── shared
│           └── kustomization.yaml
```

Here, I would have two parts for each environment: `env` and `shared`. I would overrule the namespace in `overlay/dev/env/kustomization.yaml`. That file would also include the base `base/env`, making sure that the namespace of the `shared` base is not modified. The above also illustrates which patch works (`serviceaccount-patch.yaml`) and which doesn't (`serviceaccount-patch2.yaml`).

If there is a better way to achieve this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A patch can only be applied to resources that are generated by the `kustomization.yaml` that includes the patch. In other words, running `kustomize build` without the patch defined must create the resources that you want to patch.

Running `kustomize build` in your `nested` directory produces no output -- that file includes no resources, so your patch is no-op.

I'm not entirely sure I understand your desired layout; in particular, it's not clear what the difference between `dev/` and `/dev/env/` is meant to be. You would generally set things up like this:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── service-account.yaml
└── overlay
    ├── dev
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── serviceaccount-patch.yaml
    ├── us-east
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── ...
    └── us-west
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── ...
```

Where `overlay/dev/kustomization.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base

patches:
  - path: serviceaccount-patch.yaml
    target:
      kind: ServiceAccount
      name: base
```

Running `kustomize build overlay/dev` shows that the patch is applied as expected:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: replaced
spec:
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

Comment: Good to know that indeed the patch needs to be applied to what kustomization.yaml imports as a resource. I guess I'm running into issues as I'm now trying to add patches on top of my base that uses nested kustomizations.

I noticed my example was not completely showing that, I have edited it in the question above.

Comment: To clarify the change: base was supposed to be able to be applied by itself. It has a kustomization, which in its turn loads the various apps that are defined in their own kustomizations. However, as I was overwriting the namespace in the overlays, I had to branch off the 'shared' parts into their own kustomization. Hence, the `shared`. So there's a layered structure here.

The overlays mirror the structure of base. `env` is supposed to become the namespace for `dev`, etc. This namespace is set in the overlay's kustomization.

Comment: By splitting `env` and `shared` into separate bases, I thought I could then override the namespace by using the `namespace` attribute of kustomization. In `overlays/dev/env/kustomization.yaml` I would put `namespace: dev`, for example, thus setting the namespace for all included resources. I'd consider `dev` a _base_ then, just like `shared` would be a _base_.

Comment: You can treat `dev` as a base by having `dev/env` include `..` as a resource (and then your patch would apply), rather than having `dev` include `env`.

Comment: I think that's eventually the way to go for me. Thanks, @larsks!